# Weird behavior of indexPath.section in "cellForRowAtIndexPath:"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a weird problem with the `indexPath.section` from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

I have a grouped tableview with 4 sections and I'm trying to apply a custom `UITableViewCell` for section 3, but it's not working.

When I try `if(indexPath.section==0){...}` it works (and for `section==1` and `section==2` as well) but it fails for `section==3`. (?)

I don't know why, that makes no sense.. Did someone already had this (strange) problem?

When I try `if(indexPath.row==0){...}` it works for all the 4 sections.. so..?!

Here is my code :

```
//ViewController.h
import "DirectionsTableViewCell.h"
DirectionsTableViewCell *directionsCell; // customized UITableViewCell

//ViewController.m
if (indexPath.section==3) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"directionsCell";

        DirectionsTableViewCell *cell = (DirectionsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectionsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = directionsCell;
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"defaultCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

        return cell;
    }
```

**Problem solved !**

I just added `if(indexPath.row)` and it works fine.

Finally you got this :

```
if(indexPath.section==3) {
   if(indexPath.row) {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"directionsCell";

      DirectionsTableViewCell *cell = (DirectionsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if(cell == nil) {
          [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectionsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
          cell = directionsCell;
      }

      return cell;
   }
}
```

Comment: Fails in what sense? What error or unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: I actually have had this problem. Could you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? That might help confirm my hunch.

Comment: Well, I don't have any error, but it doesn't load the custom UITableViewCell.. I still have the default one.

Comment: I know, but I have had a similar problem (not having the proper cell being loaded) with a UITableView, without any compilation errors

Comment: Hmm. Not exactly what I expected. What exactly is the problem that you are having? i.e. what do you mean by 'fails'?

Comment: When I replace `if(indexPath.section==3` by `if(indexPath.section==2)` for example, it correctly loads the custom view `DirectionsTableViewCell` but when I try this for section 3 I have the default `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're never allocating a DirectionsTableViewCell inside your `if(cell == nil)`.

In this section of your code:

```
DirectionsTableViewCell *cell = (DirectionsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectionsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = directionsCell;
        }
```

You never allocate a cell of type `DirectionsTableViewCell` for it to be reused later. I also notice you have an ivar named `directionsCell` of type `DirectionsTableViewCell`. Unless you're allocating and setting it up elsewhere, `cell = directionsCell` ends up assigning a nil object to your `cell`

Try this code instead and see if it works:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"directionsCell";

directionsCell = (DirectionsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(directionsCell == nil) {
        directionsCell = [[DirectionsTableViewCell alloc] init]; //Or whatever your initializer is
    }

    return directionsCell;
```

Comment: I'm going to fixe that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, thank you! That works! Just had to add the `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectionsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];` line. Thanks a lot Sid!